# Can you use a custom filter with PHP filter_var() and filter_input()

Tags: php

[PHP Filters](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) are pretty cool, but what do you do if the filters don't quite match what you want?  Can you create a custom filter?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can use [`FILTER_CALLBACK`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.misc.php) and provide your own filter function (as callback).